# For loop suggestions

Tags: perl

I have a field which takes values from 0 to 6,00,000

For this field values in database are say 5,6,7,8,45,91,92,93,94

I have to get free values and used value suggestions for this field

**1.USED**
Minvalue= 0  maxvalue=94( from database)

i use a for loop (i=minvalue;i<=maxvalue;i++)
Loop runs 94 times in this case and each time it checks if something matches database entries (5,6,7,45..94)

I print output ranges like
Used values:
5 to 8
45 
91 to 94

Since values are less it works fast. If there was even one entry like 490000 in database then loop would have run for a very long time.

**2.FREE**
Min value= 0 maxvalue = 600000 (from field definition)

I have the same for loop concept here too so the loop runs 5lac times. And output never comes it’s too time consuming

I would want output like
Free values :
0 to 4
9 to 44
46 to 90
95-600000

Any way to reduce for loop executions or use some other logic?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask. No clue.

Comment: I have fixed your formatting but I  think you need to add some more detail to the question. Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to loop through all values in the particular ranges. Just go through your values and look for either consecutive values (e.g current value is one greater than the previous one) or gaps, respectively. This will be much faster.

To print the used ranges

```
my @values = (5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 91, 92, 93, 94);
my $start = shift @values;
my $i = $start;
for my $v (@values) {
    if ($v > $i + 1) {
        if ($i == $start) {
            print "$start\n";
        } else {
            print "$start to $i\n";
        }

        $start = $v;
    }

    $i = $v;
}

if ($i == $start) {
    print "$start\n";
} else {
    print "$start to $i\n";
}
```

and to find the ranges of free values

```
my @values = (5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 91, 92, 93, 94);
my $i = 0;
my $max = 600000;
for my $v (@values) {
    if ($v > $i + 1) {
        print "$i to ", $v - 1, "\n";
    } elsif ($v == $i + 1) {
        print "$i\n";
    }

    $i = $v + 1;
}

if ($i < $max) {
    print "$i to $max\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I will try this and let you know. It didn't strike me as I was using a hash map and was not sorting the input.

Comment: When I find free values  for "my @values = (2,3,4,5,7, 8, 45, 91, 92, 93, 94);" the free range doesnt show value 6

Comment: @user1968965 Thank you for your test, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that.

If possible, set this database column as an `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or your SQL engine's closest alternative), so that new values will be assigned automatically. If that isn't possible, you can instead `SELECT MAX(col) + 1 FROM table` to determine the next available value (but note that this is race-prone).

In either case, *don't worry about leaving gaps*. In most applications, it isn't an issue. If domain requirements exist in your application which leave you a limited number of IDs (why?), then you will probably run into eventual issues when all your IDs are allocated anyway, so you will need to plan for this.

If you are in some really unusual situation where you have a small number of available values which need to be allocated efficiently, then you should track those values explicitly. Have a table with one row for every available value and a field indicating what it's allocated to, and search that table using something like `SELECT id FROM id_table WHERE inuse = 0 LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the database table has *N* rows, then at least one of the values between 0 and *N* inclusive must be unused, so you only need to loop at most *N*+1 times.

An efficient way to do this in Perl would be to store the used values as hash keys, and the just increment a variable in a loop until it no longer matches any key in the hash:

```
my @values = (5,6,7,8,45,91,92,93,94);

my %hash;
undef @hash{@values};

my $x = 0;
$x++ while exists $hash{$x};

# now $x is the lowest unused value
```